# How to get UITouch stregth

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I would like to get force of finger while drawing. I have seen UITouch force property but it’s always 0. You can see example in attached file. [image]

Comment: check this out might help https://krakendev.io/force-touch-recognizers/

Comment: Use the majorRadius property.

Comment: Major radius is not working. It’s like how our thumb touches screen. Not regarding pressure or force.